# No Syntax Highlighting in Ubuntu SDK

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, syntax-highlighting

I just installed Ubuntu SDK. But files open without syntax highlighting in general. Is there something missing? I use the common Text Editor. Do I need to install a further package that makes the `generic-highlighter` work?

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling this : select Tools > Options > Text Editor > Generic Highlighter.  If this does not work please leave a comment below1

Thanks, hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, I think it's already active. The location is defined and definitions are stored in the configured location. Also the fallback location is defined (katepart) and valid. Nothing the less it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Step to **Generic Highlighter** ie., *Tools >Option >Text Editor >Generic Highlighter*

Select **Download Definitions...**
[image: Download Definitions]

**Select All** and **Download Selected Definitions**
[image: Download selected Definition]

This will download highlighter definitions from internet so, wait for some time.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Many thanks, but unfortunately it does not work here....